# "Aggravate" commonly used?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I'm a non-native speaker writing a song in which I would really like to use "aggravate" in the context of "We could aggravate us everyday" (constantly annoy each other). Somehow the word just came into my mind and I'm not entirely sure if this is a valid - and somewhat common - use of the word.

So, my two questions:
1) Is the sentence "We could aggravate us everyday" correct in my context?
2) Is it more or less commonly used? After all, I wouldn't want my song to sound more like an academic paper.

Thank you.

Comment: No, to aggravate means to make a bad situation worse, not to be upsetting.  We can aggravate our sense of worry everyday, but not make the *our* situation worse.

Comment: Is this songwriting? If so, you can get away with bending the usual rules. It's a common enough word in my idiolect.

Comment: If you look up 'aggravate' in any dictionary (and such signs of research are expected on ELU) (and some commenters should also take the trouble to do research), you will find that the '**aggravate**: ... [informal]
to annoy someone:
Stop aggravating me, will you!' sense is licensed nowadays (This from [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aggravate)). // However, 'We could aggravate us everyday' is quite unacceptable, and  'We could aggravate ourselves everyday' is so unidiomatic it is not much better.

Comment: 'Aggravate' in that sense was licensed when I was a kid in the 1950s.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm not sure why you didn't correct it to "We could aggravate each other every day".

Comment: @CJ Dennis _Correct_? I'd say 'constantly annoy each other' is way better than alternatives. 'Annoy ourselves' is not unknown, so where do you get your information that 'aggravate ourselves' must be **incorrect**?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Aggravate works better with other people, rather than with oneself. "We love ourselves. We love each other." To me, those have very different meanings, and "aggravate" works the same way. Also, the OP said "in the context of 'We could aggravate us everyday' (constantly annoy **each other**)."

Comment: I agree. I just didn't like the sound of 'We could aggravate each other every day'.  So I didn't advertise the 'correct' version (Orwell's Sixth [how things sound is extremely important] is my first law, and I usually have to go by ear). But I'll try to be objective: Google results are probably a little low to reliably show idiomaticity, but for "annoy each other every day" : "aggravate each other every day" they are 576 : 2.

Answer (score 2):

> So, my two questions: 1) Is the sentence "We could aggravate us everyday" correct in my context?

It is not correct in **any** context. "us" is wrong". It has to be

1. "We could aggravate **each other** everyday." This means I would aggravate you and you would aggravate me.

or depending on the context

2. "We could aggravate **ourselves** everyday [by having to walk for miles to get the water]." This means that we would both become aggravated **by something**, e.g. [by having to walk for miles to get the water].

**The belief that "to aggravate" only means "to make something worse" is erroneous, and has been since the 16th century**:

OED:

> **6. a. transitive. To exasperate (a person); to incense, embitter; to provoke, arouse the dislike, dissatisfaction, or concern of; (also in weakened use) to annoy or irritate. Now chiefly colloquial**.
>
> 1598   J. Florio Worlde of Wordes   "Essagerare, to exasperat, to prouoke, to irritate, to agrauat, to exaggerat, to amplifie, to extoll."
>
> 1965   A. Lurie Nowhere City xvii. 186   *‘Don't aggravate yourself. It'll be no trouble’*.
>
> 1998   Rec. Collector Apr. 76/1   *None of the band was over twenty, their brattish antics aggravated the cognoscenti and they didn't even play on their singles*.